# react native what is the use of React$Node

Tags: react-native

on React native,
by default react-native init project, I see

```
const App: () => React$Node = () => {
```

but this is what I used before

```
const App = () => {
```

What is that "React$Node" in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its type `definition from Flow`, it means that constant App is of type function and it `returns ReactNode`.

ReactNode is one of these types: `ReactChild | ReactFragment | ReactPortal | boolean | null | undefined`

This means the function App can return, any `valid JSX (in react native its anything from View, Text, ScrollView, .etc), ReactFragment, React.Portal, boolean, null, undefined`

If you are confused about the dollar sign, here is a link with an explanation.

https://www.saltycrane.com/flow-type-cheat-sheet/latest/

For easy, you can think of it as its Node from React (think of it as scope/namespace)

**React$Node is a type defined in react.js**

```
 declare type React$Node =
  | null
  | boolean
  | number
  | string
  | React$Element<any>
  | React$Portal
  | Iterable<?React$Node>;
```